How can onClick on Geom or Label of bizcharts?
I have label of custom barchart based on bizcharts?
How can add onlick on Label or Geom to get the data?
I try using onCLick inside Geom
<Geom 
 onClick={ev => {
            console.log('Clicked data:', ev);
            const { data: clickedData } = ev; // Access the clicked data

            handleLabelClick && handleLabelClick(clickedData[xAxisKey], clickedData[yAxisKey]);
          }}
>

or onClick on Label
label={[
            `${xAxisKey}*${yAxisKey}`,
            (label, value) => {
              return {
                content: formatNumber(value), // Format your label
                style: {
                  fontWeight: '700',
                  cursor: 'pointer',
                },
                // Capture label click
                onClick: () => {
                  console.log('onclick barchart');
                  handleLabelClick && handleLabelClick(label, value);
                },
              };
            },
          ]}

